# useCallback, to fetch a data array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My fetchData function using an array?
I am using a reducer to globally store the images, but here is where the fetch occurs.

1. Question, Should it be here or in the reducer with the other actions like add, change delete?
2. Is returning an array going to work I remember something about an array not being the best choice for a change object since react does a shallow compare?  Should I change it to a class that has a last change date that is updated through the reducer each time?

   ```
   export function BaseMediaLayout() {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState({ open: false, item: null});
    const [cardData, dispatch] = useReducer(cardDataReducer, initialCapturedImages);
    let props: ImageDialogProps = null;

    const fetchData = React.useCallback(async()=> {
        const data = await GetImages(10);
        dispatch({
            type: 'fetched',
            capturedImages: data,
            id: "",
            text: "",
            capturedImage: undefined
        })
        return data;
      }, cardData)


    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
      }, cardData);

    const onClick = (item: CapturedImage): void =>{
        props.title = "Image Title";
        props.open =true;
        props.onClose = onClose;
        props.item = null;
    }

    const onClose = (): void =>{
        props.item = null;
        props.open = false;
        props.title = null;
        setOpen(props);
    }

    return (

        <CardDataContext.Provider value={cardData}>
        <CardDataDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        <MenuAppBar/>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
            { cardData.map(i => {
                return (
                    <Grid xs={4}>
                    <MediaCard onClick={onClick} image={i} />
                </Grid>
                )
            })};

        </Grid>
        </CardDataDispatchContext.Provider>
    </CardDataContext.Provider>
    )
   ```

   }